# parameter in hudson

Tags: parameters, hudson

I have 2 projects in hudson and I want to make a difference between them. I can do it with theirs names, but I can not use this in hudson.
I tried to use string parameter from "This build is parameterized" but I can not use them at "invoke ant" there at "Properties". I sent like myparam= ${env.BSYST}, BSYST-is my name at string parameter and  after I build is written ${env.BSYST} this value instead what I write at "This build requires parameters:
BSYST:   ". 
Do you know what is wrong or can you give me another solution at how to send the name of my project and  in build.xml to make an "if" and do different things?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters within Hudson are just local environment variables; you cannot pull variables into the parameters from other sources.

However, within the configuration area of the job in Hudson, you can add a build step. You should have the options to invoke Ant and Maven targets (at least you do in Jenkins) where you can specify the build file. At the least you can execute shell. Within shell, your SVN working copy is within scope and can be read, i.e. you can read and parse your build.xml. Remember, this is normal shell so if you want to echo a variable you can do so.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I solved the problem: at post-build actions at " Trigger parameterized build on other projects" I put a predefined parameter and it is send to all my projects that I named at "Projects to build"